# Parse a json file to get the right columns to insert into bigquery

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery

I'm relatively new to Python and I am trying to get some exchange rate data from the ECB free api:

GET https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=GBP

I want to ultimately end up with this data in a bigquery table. Loading the data to BQ is fine, but getting it into the right column/row format before sending it the BQ is the problem.

I want to end up with a table like this:

```
Currency    Rate      Date
CAD         1.629..   2019-08-27
HKD         9.593..   2019-08-27
ISK         152.6..   2019-08-27
...         ...       ...
```

I've tried a few things but not quite got there yet:

```
# api-endpoint
URL = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=GBP"

# sending get request and saving the response as response object
r = requests.get(url=URL)

# extracting data in json format
data = r.json()

with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data['rates'], outfile)

a_dict = {'date': '2019-08-26'}

with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data.update(a_dict)

with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)

print(data)
```

Here is the original json file:

```
{  
   "rates":{  
      "CAD":1.6296861353,
      "HKD":9.593490542,
      "ISK":152.6759753684,
      "PHP":64.1305429339,
      "DKK":8.2428443501,
      "HUF":363.2604778172,
      "CZK":28.4888284523,
      "GBP":1.0,
      "RON":5.2195062629,
      "SEK":11.8475893558,
      "IDR":17385.9684034803,
      "INR":87.6742617713,
      "BRL":4.9997236134,
      "RUB":80.646191945,
      "HRK":8.1744110201,
      "JPY":130.2223254066,
      "THB":37.5852652759,
      "CHF":1.2042718318,
      "EUR":1.1055465269,
      "MYR":5.1255348081,
      "BGN":2.1622278974,
      "TRY":7.0550451616,
      "CNY":8.6717964026,
      "NOK":11.0104695256,
      "NZD":1.9192287707,
      "ZAR":18.6217151449,
      "USD":1.223287232,
      "MXN":24.3265563331,
      "SGD":1.6981194654,
      "AUD":1.8126540855,
      "ILS":4.3032293014,
      "KRW":1482.7479464473,
      "PLN":4.8146551248
   },
   "base":"GBP",
   "date":"2019-08-23"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome! How about this, as one way to tackle your problem.

```
# import the pandas library so we can use it's from_dict function:
import pandas as pd

# subset the json to a dict of exchange rates and country codes:
d = data['rates']

# create a dataframe from this data, using pandas from_dict function:
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')

# add a column for date (this value is taken from the json data):
df['date'] = data['date']

# name our columns, to keep things clean
df.columns = ['rate','date']
```

This gives you:

```
    rate    date
CAD 1.629686    2019-08-23
HKD 9.593491    2019-08-23
ISK 152.675975  2019-08-23
PHP 64.130543   2019-08-23
...
```

In this case the currency is the index of the dataframe, if you'd prefer it as column of it's own just add:
`df['currency'] = df.index`

You can then write this dataframe out to a .csv file, or write it into BigQuery.

For this i'd recommend you take a look at [The BigQuery Client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries), this can be a little hard to get your head around at first, so you may also want to check out [pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_gbq.html), which is easier, but less robust (see [this link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/pandas-gbq-migration) for more detail on Client library vs. a pandas function.

Comment: Thanks for the help, that worked great!

Pandas worked great to get the format I wanted. I ended up writing the dataframe to a csv and loading to a BQ table without pandas though.

I'll post my final script in a comment below for anyone interested.

And thanks for the welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ben P for the help.

Here is my script that works for those interested. It uses an internal library my team uses for the BQ load, but the rest is pandas and requests:

```
from aa.py.gcp import GCPAuth, GCPBigQueryClient
from aa.py.log import StandardLogger
import requests, os, pandas as pd

# Connect to BigQuery
logger = StandardLogger('test').logger
auth = GCPAuth(logger=logger)
credentials_path = 'XXX'
credentials = auth.get_credentials(credentials_path)
gcp_bigquery = GCPBigQueryClient(logger=logger)
gcp_bigquery.connect(credentials)

# api-endpoint
URL = "https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=GBP"

# sending get request and saving the response as response object
r = requests.get(url=URL)

# extracting data in json format
data = r.json()

# extract rates object from json
d = data['rates']

# split currency and rate for dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index')

# add date element to dataframe
df['date'] = data['date']

#column names
df.columns = ['rate', 'date']

# print dataframe
print(df)

# write dateframe to csv
df.to_csv('data.csv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')

#########################################
# write csv to BQ table
file_path = os.getcwd()
file_name = 'data.csv'
dataset_id = 'Testing'
table_id = 'Exchange_Rates'

response = gcp_bigquery.load_file_into_table(file_path, file_name, dataset_id, table_id, source_format='CSV', field_delimiter="\t", create_disposition='CREATE_NEVER', write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',skip_leading_rows=1)
```